# Python unittest patch using custom mock class

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am testing a relatively simple piece of code that uses two relatively complex object that requires disk access. The complex objects are from a library. I would like to mock these library objects and assert that some of their member functions were called with particular values, depending on the input.

The calls that I use rely on some internal state of the library objects. I recognise that I can mock every function call on the complex objects individually, and set a `return_value` before each. This seems much messier and painful than it needs to be, though.

It seems like you should be able to provide a custom class and wrap it with a Mock object to track all the calls to member functions. I've spent a few hours trying to make sense of the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html), and the closest I've found is the `wraps` argument. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to replace all the members with mocks that wrap, instead, it just uses the member variables of the mock object, only tracking the calls to `__init__`.

e.g. in **module_a.py:**

```py
# Assuming some library class that acts something like this:
class A:
  def __init__(self, filename):
    self.filename = filename
  def get(self):
    # ... Some complicated code, involving state and disk access ...
    return something

def some_fnc(filename):
  a = A(filename)
  a.get()
  a.get()
  a.get()
  a.get()
```

in **test_module_a.py:**

```py
import unittest
import unittest.mock

import module_a

class MockA:
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.i = 0
    pass
  def get(self):
    # Fake version that returns dummy values,
    # but more complicated than simply returning some value.
    # Easy to reason about. If this gets complicated then you have problems.
    print(self.i, 'is gotten')
    if self.i > 3:
      return 5
    self.i += 1
    return 1

class SomeFncTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  @unittest.mock.patch('module_a.A', wraps=MockA)
  def test_it(self, m):
    module_a.some_fnc('in_file')
    m.assert_called_with('in_file')
    m.get.assert_called()
```

MockA.get is called, and the first assert passes, but the second assert fails.

Is there some functionality that I'm missing? Is it possible to do what I want? Is there any reason why what I'm suggesting is particularly bad?

Comment: It looks like you actually want `side_effect=[1, 1, 1, 5]` for the get method. Note that you're mocking the *class*, so the *"real result"* that `wraps` returns is the *unwrapped* instance, that's why only `__init__` calls are tracked.

Comment: This is just a toy example. I want the side effects to be programmatically determined. (i.e. the side_effects are based on the inputs, e.g. a function that is just a switch statement).

Comment: A side effect can also be a function, as you only have one method. But your solution below also addresses it, wrapping an instance rather than the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `patch`ed Mock object to return an instance of MagicMock that wraps your mock class by setting that as the return value when the callee tries to instantiate `module_a.A`.

```py
class SomeFncTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  @unittest.mock.patch('module_a.A')
  def test_it(self, m):
    mock_a = MagicMock(wraps=MockA())
    m.return_value = mock_a

    module_a.some_fnc('in_file')

    m.assert_called_with('in_file')
    mock_a.get.assert_called()
```

There is a distinction between `m` the Mock that essentially mocks `A.__call__`, and `mock_a`, a mocked instantiation of the `A` class (which provides actual function return values by wrapping an instance of `MockA`).